# Meaning of HCLK, FCLK, DCLK, PCLK

Tags: microcontroller, microprocessor

Can somebody please clarify the meaning of these acronyms in the context of ARM Cortex:

- HCLK
- FCLK
- DCLK
- PCLK

I think HCLK means half clock? I know that PCLK is related to APB, so maybe it means peripheral clock? I am clueless about the other two.

Comment: the chip you're referring to is not an ARM product itself – the design of the CPU core of it is (that's what Cortex-M is, a design for a CPU core). The clocking environment, and all the peripherals attached to the CPU core, are designed by the designers of your MCU – microchip/atmel, NXP, ST, Cypress, TI, Maxim, … **Your chip has a datasheet; at least link to that here**.

Comment: I won't. The point of my question was to understand whether existed a general meaning. Dave already addressed that pont clearly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no universal meaning for these acronyms. You need to look at the specific chip's datasheet in order to understand how they're used.